# Dash Datatable disappearing while switching between Tabs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a Dash app with 2 Tabs and on one Tab I have an upload button while on the other Tab the uploaded dataset is being shown. After uploading the data, it is shown on the second tab but when I switch to the first Tab and come back again to the second Tab, the data table is not there anymore. I have tried using persistence and persistence-type but it doesn't work. Here is the code for the data table

```
@du.callback(
    output=Output('output-datatable', 'children'),
    id='upload-data',
)
def get_a_list(filenames):

    data1=pd.read_excel(filenames[0])    

    return dash_table.DataTable(
        data = data1.to_dict('records'), 
        columns = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in data1.columns], 
        page_size =15, persistence = True, persistence_type = 'memory')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of persistence, use dcc.store
In the layout:

```
dcc.Store(id='store-data', data=[], storage_type='local')
```

Callback function:

```
@du.callback(
    output=Output('store-data', 'data'),
    input = Input(id='upload-data','children')
)
```

Also check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLykSQNIM1E